# Tweening the oval primitive

Tags: flash

Is there a way to tween the oval primitive from within flash? I would like to do a tween where I move the start angle, but I can't seem to be able to tween the oval. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to tween the oval through ActionScript (which I assume, since this is a programming forum), you need to turn the oval into a MovieClip or Sprite, since the primitive oval as such is not an object you can reference from ActionScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'd like to start out with a small pie and tween until you get a full circle, right?

Well, afaik you need to do this with multiple stages in between and shape hints. For the final circle, you'll have to put this in a separate keyframe since the tween will otherwise try to move the center up to the enclosing circle. It should be a little tweaking but surely possible.